# How does Javascript(NodeJS) handle scope and context with regard to events

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, event-handling, dom-events

I'm a bit confused in a situation,
given the sample code here where I'm loading several urls, and connected the event Listener:

```
var pages= Array();
var loading= Array();

for(i=0; i < urls.length; i++){
var page =new WebPage(urls[i]);

   page.onLoadStarted = function() {
       loading[i]= true;
       console.log('Loading started');
   };    
   pages[i]=page;

}
```

I have 5 urls, and I get 5 times "Loading started" in the console output, however the loading array had only one value defined (true) all the rest are "undefined";
Looks like when the event is triggered  `loading[i]= true;` uses the last value of I  to access the array instead of using its address. How can I fix that ?

I've tried adding a property to the page object, but same thing happens;

Here is what I've tried:

```
var pages= Array();

for(i=0; i < urls.length; i++){
var page =new WebPage(urls[i]);

   page.onLoadStarted = function() {
       page.loading= true;
       console.log('Loading started');
   };    
   pages[i]=page;

}
```

Comment: Just use `for(let i=0;...)` or wrap the event handler in an IIFE, if you can't rely on ES2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `onLoadStarted` is an event handler then the `for` loop is executed much faster than the all the event handlers. In that time `i` is `5` and during each function call, the sixth index of the array is populated with a `true` value. As the lower indices of array do no have any set value you get such output.

One option is using the `Array.prototype.forEach` or `Array.prototype.map` method. Both functions take a function as the handler. The handler which is a function, creates a new scope and remembers the defined values.

```
urls.forEach(function(url /* element */, i /* index */) {
   var page = new WebPage(url);

   page.onLoadStarted = function() {
       loading[i]= true;
       console.log('Loading started');
   };    
   pages[i]=page;
})
```

Comment: yea, i ended up understanding that, but why is my 2nd attempt(code) didn't work as well ? i din't use any index; but linked to the object it self as a property, and later when i check all pages for that property, same thing only one is define and has true value. i would really like to understand that.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code (es6)

```
    let pages = Array();
    urls.map((url,i) =>{
     let page = new WebPage(urls[i]);

     page.onLoadStarted(() =>{
      loading[i] = true;
      console.log('Loading started');
     })
```

(es5)

```
    var pages = Array();
    urls.map(function(url,i){
     var page = new WebPage(urls[i]);

     page.onLoadStarted(function(){
      loading[i] = true;
      console.log('Loading started');
     })
```

Comment: it doesn't work with let, seems that its not supported in nodejs

Comment: use a transpiler [babel-node](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation)